# Read access violation after shuffling vector multiple times

Tags: c++, vector, shuffle

For a school project I need to shuffle a vector with unique pointers.
However when I do this I get a read access violation error after some time.
I create the vector and then call the shuffle. This I do multiple times. I just create the vector with the values and shuffle it once and after a couple of times I get the read access violation error.

code

```
    int RandomEngine::generateRandomInt(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minValue, maxValue);
        std::cout << "Random getal van " << minValue << " tot " << maxValue << std::endl;
        return distribution(def_rand_engine);
    }

    void RandomEngine::shuffleCharacterCards(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CharacterCard>>& cards)
    {
        // Succeeds once but with multiple swaps read access violation
        //auto randomInt = generateRandomInt(0, cards.size() - 1);
        //iter_swap(cards.begin() + randomInt, cards.begin());

        // Read access violation
        //for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
        //{
        //  std::swap(cards[i], cards[std::rand() % cards.size()]);
        //}

        // Read access violation
        //std::shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), std::mt19937{ def_rand_engine});

        // Read access violation
        //std::random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end());



    // Read access violation
    //std::shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device()()));
}
```

Other class where I call the shuffle from the static class

```
void CharacterCardStack::prepare()
{
    std::cout << "Preparing CharacterCardStack..." << std::endl;
    if(cards_.size() > 2)
    {
        // Shuffle the cards
        RandomEngine::shuffleCharacterCards(cards_);

        // Burn the first card
        burnedCharacterCard_ = std::move(cards_[0]);
        std::cout << "Burned charactercard: " << burnedCharacterCard_->getName() << std::endl;
        cards_.erase(cards_.begin());
        // Als de open kaart een koning is dan moet deze vervangen worden door een ander.
        if(cards_[0]->getName() == "Koning")
        {
            turnedCharacterCard_ = std::move(cards_[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            turnedCharacterCard_ = std::move(cards_[0]);
        }
        std::cout << "Turned charactercard: " << turnedCharacterCard_->getName() << std::endl;
        cards_.erase(cards_.begin());
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "CharacterCardStack::prepare cards size is " << cards_.size() << std::endl;
        throw std::exception("Error...");
    }
    for (const auto& c : cards_)
    {
        std::cout << "Other card: " << c->getName() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "CharacterCardStack prepared" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have flow in your logic, you move out either first or the second element based on condition:

```
    if(cards_[0]->getName() == "Koning")
    {
        turnedCharacterCard_ = std::move(cards_[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        turnedCharacterCard_ = std::move(cards_[0]);
    }
```

but then unconditionaly erase the first element:

```
cards_.erase(cards_.begin());
```

so you may end up with moved out pointers.

Simple fix could be:

```
    if(cards_[0]->getName() == "Koning")
    {
        std::swap( cards_[0], cards_[1] );
    }
    turnedCharacterCard_ = std::move(cards_[0]);
    std::cout << "Turned charactercard: " << turnedCharacterCard_->getName() << std::endl;
    cards_.erase(cards_.begin());
```

this way it is easier to keep it correct and I would prefer use `cards.front()` instead of `cards_[0]`, which is I think more readable in this case.

Comment: Maybe you are right but it only happens if I call the RandomEngine::shuffleCharacterCards(cards_) method. If I remove that line it works.

Comment: Let me guess without shuffle "Koning" always stays at the end and bug is not exposed?

Comment: Yes that is true

Comment: IT WORKED!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!